# How do I aggregate by time and keep the percentage that different aggregated values accounted for in an interval?

Tags: r, aggregate

I am relatively new to R so apologies if this is too trivial..

I have data which roughly lookes like this:

`dat <- data.frame(Time =c("12:00:00","12:00:00","12:00:00","14:00:00","14:00:00","14:00:00" ),X = c("A","B","B","A","B","C"))`

where **Time** is the time of  measurements (recorded as a 2 h interval) and **X** the measured variable.

I want to aggregate (?) the rows which have the same **Time** value but keep all the different **X** values instead of calculating the mean or sum; ideally I want to get the percentage that each **X** value made up per aggregated time interval. So something like this:

| Time | % A | % B | % C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12:00:00 | 0.333 | 0.666 | 0.0 |
| 14:00:00 | 0.333 | 0.333 | 0.333 |

Is there a way to achieve this? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### base R

```r
xt <- t(apply(xtabs(~ Time + X, data = dat), 1, function(z) z/sum(z)))
xt <- cbind(as.data.frame(xt), Time = rownames(xt))
rownames(xt) <- NULL
xt
#           A         B         C     Time
# 1 0.3333333 0.6666667 0.0000000 12:00:00
# 2 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333 14:00:00
```

### dlpyr

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  count(Time, X) %>%
  mutate(n = n/sum(n)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "X", values_from = "n") %>%
  mutate(across(-Time, ~ if_else(is.na(.), 0, .)))
# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#   Time         A     B     C
#   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 12:00:00 0.167 0.333 0    
# 2 14:00:00 0.167 0.167 0.167
```

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
datDT <- as.data.table(dat)
out <- dcast(datDT[, .N, by = .(Time, X)][, N := N/sum(N)],
      Time ~ X, value.var = "N"
  )[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(z) fifelse(is.na(z), 0, z)), .SDcols = cols]
out
#        Time         A         B         C
#      <char>     <num>     <num>     <num>
# 1: 12:00:00 0.1666667 0.3333333 0.0000000
# 2: 14:00:00 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667
```